# Insert an image inside a GtkLabel?

Tags: c, gtk, vala, pango

I would like to insert an image inside a GtkLabel but the `<image>` tag doesn't exists in Pango. I also tried to using the hacky way that consist of having a `<span class="image"></span>` and setting it a `background-image` via the CSS but `class=""` isn't a valid Pango attribute.

My question is: Is their a way to insert an image inside a label ? Not before or after but inside. Basically i would like to add emojis in my instant messenger messages.

I searched the web, and here but doesn't found a solution that fit my needs. :/

Thanks in advance for replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seem that doing this isn't possible. The proper way to do it seems to be using a GtkTextView. For peoples that are running into the same issue of me, just run `gtk3-demo` → Text View → Multiple Views.

Answer (score 0):

I posted some full code of Pango's handling of images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017155/pango-cairo-is-there-an-existing-approach-for-handling-img-style-tags-in-te/30415800?noredirect=1#comment51904962_30415800). Pango's image handling is very limited but might be able to handle your simple requirements.