# Pango layout flow around container (image)

Tags: c++, layout, text, text-rendering, pango

I'm using Pango for text layouting without the cairo backend (currently testing with the win32 backend). And I like to know if pango is capable of a flow layout around an image, or any given container. Or maybe inside a custom container.

Something like this: [Flow around image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpNd2.jpg)

I have checked many examples and the Pango API and didn't found such a feature. Maybe I'm missing something or Pango does not have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017155/pango-cairo-is-there-an-existing-approach-for-handling-img-style-tags-in-te/30415800#30415800), you can't. I went through the source code Pango graphics handling is primitive to the point of uselessness. Unless there's been some major reworking in the past year, which the release notes don't indicate, it's probably the same now.

The image you provide as an example is only available as PDF at the moment which requires every line, word and glyph be hard-positioned on the page. While theoretically possible to check the alpha channel of the image to wrap the text around the actual image instead of the block it contains, this has not (to the best of my knowledge) ever been implemented in a dynamic output system.

Pango, specifically, cannot even open "holes" in the text for graphics to be added later and, at the code level, doesn't even have the concept of a multi-line cell - hence a line being the size of its largest component.

Your best bet is to look at WebKit for more complex displays. I, for one, have pretty much given up on Pango and it seems to be getting less popular.