# Don't insert hyphens when using character wrap with GtkSourceView

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject, pango

I have a `GtkSource.View` with the wrap mode set to `Gtk.WrapMode.CHAR`. When it wraps, it inserts `-` at the end of the line. How can I prevent that?

In my research I found that the Pango library has a `attr_insert_hyphens_new(False)` function, which returns a `Pango.Attribute`, but I don't understand how you're meant to use these Pango attributes.

---

Current code:

```py
view = GtkSource.View()
view.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.CHAR)

context = view.get_pango_context()
attrList = Pango.AttrList()
layout = Pango.Layout(context)

attr = Pango.attr_insert_hyphens_new(False)
attr.start_index = Pango.ATTR_INDEX_FROM_TEXT_BEGINNING
attr.end_index = Pango.ATTR_INDEX_TO_TEXT_END
attrList.insert(attr)
layout.set_attributes(attrList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encountered the same problem,
I found 2 way to avoid hyphens.
//seems both need gtk4

### A. pango markup `insert_hyphens` Attributes

need Pango >= 1.44

https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/pango_markup.html#:~:text=insert_hyphens

NOTE: chrome browser can anchor to keyword.

even pygtk with Pango 1.50
no runtime error, but seems no effect with gtk3.
(maybe gtk3 not handle it right)

### B. Gtk.TextTag:insert-hyphens

need gtk4

https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.TextTag.html#properties:~:text=TextTag%3Ainsert%2Dhyphens

gtk3 will got error:

> TypeError: gobject `GtkTextTag' doesn't support property` insert_hyphens'

---

### demo code

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


# set text without hyphens by markup
def test_markup(tb: Gtk.TextBuffer):
    # insert-hyphens='no' or insert_hyphens='false' both work
    s = '123 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddd'
    s = '<span insert-hyphens="no" color="green">' + s + '</span>'
    # tb.set_text(s)
    tb.insert_markup(tb.get_end_iter(), s, -1)


# set text without hyphens by textTag
def test_tag(tb: Gtk.TextBuffer):
    s = '456 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccc ddddddddd'
    tb.set_text(s)
    tag1 = tb.create_tag("test1", foreground="red", insert_hyphens=False)
    tb.apply_tag(tag1, tb.get_start_iter(), tb.get_end_iter())
    # tb.apply_tag(tag1, tb.get_start_iter(), tb.get_iter_at_offset(3))


def on_activate(app):
    win = Gtk.ApplicationWindow(application=app)

    tv: Gtk.TextView = Gtk.TextView.new()
    tv.set_size_request(150, 50)
    tv.set_wrap_mode(Gtk.WrapMode.CHAR)

    tb: Gtk.TextBuffer = tv.get_buffer()

    test_markup(tb)
    # test_tag(tb)

    box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
    box.append(tv)
    box.set_size_request(400, 300)
    box.append(Gtk.Button(label="hello"))

    win.present()
    win.set_child(box)


app = Gtk.Application()
app.connect('activate', on_activate)
app.run(None)
```

Comment: `<span insert-hyphens="no">` works for me with gtk3

Comment: @user2804197 
could you tell the version of `PyGObject` and `libgtk-3-0`:
`pip3 show pygobject`  and `apt list --installed 'libgtk-3-*'`

Comment: `gtk-launch --version` output may show same version with `libgtk-3-*`

Comment: I'm on Debian, where I think the Python bindings come from `gir1.2-gtk-3.0` of which I have version `3.24.24-4+deb11u2` installed.  `libgtk-3-0` is also at version `3.24.24-4+deb11u2`.

Comment: B works, just have to remove and re-add the tag every time the text changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the pango attribute list from the context and then insert the new attribute into the list.

There's an example in my answer to a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017155/pango-cairo-is-there-an-existing-approach-for-handling-img-style-tags-in-te/30415800#30415800) where the shape attribute is inserted.

```
  PangoContext    *ctxt = gtk_widget_get_pango_context (pWidget);
  PangoAttrList   *attList = pango_attr_list_new();
  PangoAttribute  *attr;
  PangoLayout     *Pango = pango_layout_new (ctxt);


  attr = pango_attr_shape_new_with_data(&r, &r, pImg, NULL, NULL);
  attr->start_index = 0; attr->end_index = 1;
  pango_attr_list_insert (attList, attr);
  pango_layout_set_attributes (Pango, attList);
```

Comment: Tried to implement this. No errors, but the behavior didn't change either. I added my code to the question body.

Comment: One difference that does stand out is that I'm attaching a new attribute list and you're using an existing one. Pango is kind of finicky so see what happens if you set via a new one.